# Time Complexity of a map in java

Tags: java, string, maps, coding-efficiency

what is the time complexity of a program using maps to find the occurrences of each character in a string? Is it efficient to use it over other solutions?

```
 for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))
            map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
            else
            map.put(s.charAt(i),1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.put()` and `.get()` of a `HashMap` are `O(1)` - constant time.

The time complexity of this code is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of `s`.